# Difference output for partition size from parted and df -hP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, parted

I have a partition `/dev/sdb` before with 100 GB only (only 1 virtual partition: `/dev/sdb1`). Now, `/dev/sdb` has been increased to **480 GB** but I don't know how to increase `/dev/sdb1` to 480 GB as well.

I tried with parted:

```
 sudo umount /dev/sdb1
 sudo parted /dev/sdb resizepart 1 483000M
```

Then check again:

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) select /dev/sdb1
Using /dev/sdb1
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdb1: 483GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  483GB  483GB  ext4
```

However, with **df -hP** **it still shows /dev/sdb1 with 100 GB.**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  936K  395M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        59G  5.7G   51G  11% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  144K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
auto_in_data    8.2T  7.3T  939G  89% /media/sf_auto_in_data
/dev/sdb1        99G   70G   25G  75% /rasdata
```

So what am I missing to make `df -hP` also show `/dev/sdb1` with 480GB?

Answer (score 2):

You changed the partition size but you did not resize the filesystem on it. To do this use:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I need to run this command after parted :)

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb1
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem at /dev/sdb1 is mounted on /rasdata; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 7, new_desc_blocks = 29
The filesystem on /dev/sdb1 is now 117919666 blocks long.
```

Then, check with df -hP

```
/dev/sdb1       443G   70G  355G  17% /rasdata
```